# Aligning Equations with Variable Number of Anchors

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align, alignat

I'm trying to align some equations, but I want a variable number of anchors per line.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    a &= a',& \quad b &= b' \\
    c &= c',& \quad d &= d' \\
    e &= (e'_1 + \cdots + e'_n)(e''_1 + \cdots + e''_n)(e'''_1 + \cdots + e'''_n)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

The first two lines should have two anchors, aligning their `=` signs. The final line is much longer and only has a single `=` on it. I want this to be aligned with the left-most `=` of the other two lines.

The way it is currently written, the second `=` sign on the first two lines is far off to the right, after the entirety of the bottom line. In essence, adding the bottom line shouldn't change the relative positioning of the other four `=` signs. It may change their position on the page as the whole thing should be centred.

I've tried this with every incarnation of `align/ed/at` that I can think of, but have not been successful! I'd rather not use things like `\phantom{a}` to manually move stuff around if I can avoid it. Also, things like `\mathrlap` aren't so helpful because they aren't taken into account when doing the centralising.

---

To be completely clear, I want the entire display to be centralised. This includes the fact that the last row is the longest, so it should be centralised. I want all three of the left-most `=` signs aligned and the right two also aligned, even though `a'` and `c'` are different lengths---of course, in my actual application, they're more complicated than just `a'` and `c'`.

The precise code follow.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    N_0 &\coloneqq L_0,& \quad N_k &\coloneqq L_{f(k+1)} / L_{f(k)} \\
    S_0 &\coloneqq 0,& \quad S_{k+1} &\coloneqq S_k + 2 d^2 L_{f(k)} T_{f(k)} N_k; \\
    C_k &\coloneqq \cap_{i \in \overline{\mathcal Q}(i_0; N_k), \: m \in [2 d^2 L_{f(k)} N_k]} \bigl( \mathcal P_{f(k),k}(i) \cap \mathcal G_{f(k),k}(i; S_k + (m-1) T_k) \bigr)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The alignment tag should indicate horizontal, not vertical.

Comment: @barbarabeeton oops, yes!

Answer (score 2):

Cheat!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe} % to show centering

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\begin{alignedat}{2}
  \mathllap{N_0} &\coloneqq L_0, &\qquad\qquad N_k &\coloneqq L_{f(k+1)} / L_{f(k)} \\
  \mathllap{S_0} &\coloneqq 0,   &\qquad\qquad S_{k+1} &\coloneqq S_k + 2 d^2 L_{f(k)} T_{f(k)} N_k; \\
  \end{alignedat}
\\
C_k &\coloneqq \bigcap\nolimits_{i \in \overline{\mathcal Q}(i_0; N_k), \: 
  m \in [2 d^2 L_{f(k)} N_k]} \bigl( \mathcal P_{f(k),k}(i) \cap \mathcal G_{f(k),k}(i; S_k + (m-1) T_k) \bigr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I use an outer align and the `\coloneqq` symbols are the point of alignments; the inner `alignedat` has zero width entries in the first column and the last line happily has the widest item.

[image]

Comment: This appeared to me to be the best option. It doesn't really matter what the spacing between the two parts on the first line is---`\quad` was somewhat arbitrary---and more important to have it correctly centralised. But it does have some issues. As I said, my actual displays are more complicated. My final line is actually $$e = \cap_{i \in \overline Q(i_0; N_k), \: m \in [2 d^2 L_{f(k)} N_k]} \big( ... \bigr)$$. (Don't judge: it's still in draft notation!) I can't put the `&&` inside the subscript...

Comment: @SamOT I can't answer what you don't ask, sorry…

Comment: Indeed. But I did say that the things were more complicated and you did say that yours is a 'cheat'. This 'cheat' works in a simple case, but doesn't work in more complicated cases. Perhaps you can edit your answer to acknowledge this? Otherwise it looks like it's a solution

Comment: @SamOT I provided a better cheat for the real formula.

Comment: Ah, that's very good! I was trying to use `\aligned/at` inside another `align` environment, but the issue was that I could only anchor the left-most part of the first two `:=`. I didn't think of using `\mathllap` for the very first parts, as you did! Sure, the centralisation is still wrong: it's too far to the left, since it doesn't take into account the `\mathllap`---you can see this by replacing `N_0` with some long formula---but it's pretty minor in this case. Excellent! It's a shame there isn't some way of having some 'persistent' anchor, but your cheat is very close to the desired result!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the `IEEEeqnarray` environment from the [`IEEEtrantools` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools).

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rClrCl}
    a &=& a',& \quad b &=& b' \\
    c &=& c',& \quad d &=& d' \\
    e &=& \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{4}{l}{(e'_1 + \cdots + e'_n)(e''_1 + \cdots + e''_n)(e'''_1 + \cdots + e'''_n)}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rClrCl}
    N_0 &\coloneqq& L_0,& \quad N_k &\coloneqq& L_{f(k+1)} / L_{f(k)} \\
    S_0 &\coloneqq& 0,  & \quad S_{k+1} &\coloneqq& S_k + 2 d^2 L_{f(k)} T_{f(k)} N_k; \\
    C_k &\coloneqq& \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{4}{l}{\cap_{i \in \overline{\mathcal Q}(i_0; N_k), \: m \in [2 d^2 L_{f(k)} N_k]} \bigl( \mathcal P_{f(k),k}(i) \cap \mathcal G_{f(k),k}(i; S_k + (m-1) T_k) \bigr)}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now this is almost basically perfect! I would prefer not to use the `IEEE` packages, sticking with just `align/ed/at`, but maybe this is necessary. It's a shame that the `align/ed/at` ones doesn't have an analogous 'multi-column' option

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is cheating.  I've simply copied @Zarko's example and made the adjustment I suggested in my comment.  (However, this answer, along with my comment, have been deleted by the author.

The suggestion was to examine the aligned display with lines of uneven length, determine what part of the longest line was "too long", and insert that as a `\phantom` on the next-longest line (within the subsidiary alignment).  Granted, this is a bit of a hack, but it's much easier to accomplish than trying to construct a custom environment.

```
 \begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Text above the display.  Make it two lines so that the width of the text
block is obvious.  Make it two lines so that the width of the text
block is obvious.
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    a & = a',   &\qquad   b &= b' \\
    c & = c',   &\qquad   d &= d'
         \phantom{\quad (e''_1 + \cdots + e''_n)(e'''_1 + \cdots + e'''_n)}\\
    e & = \mathrlap{(e'_1 + \cdots + e'_n)(e''_1 + \cdots + e''_n)(e'''_1 + \cd\
ots + e'''_n)}
\end{alignat*}
Some more text directly following the display.

Let's do this again, without adding the \verb+\phantom+.
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    a & = a',   &\qquad   b &= b' \\
    c & = c',   &\qquad   d &= d' \\
    e & = \mathrlap{(e'_1 + \cdots + e'_n)(e''_1 + \cdots + e''_n)(e'''_1 + \cdots + e'''_n)}
\end{alignat*}
Some final text.
\end{document}
```

The reason for the `\phantom` in the second line is to make all lines of the display the same width.  The effect of doing this can be seen by comparing the second display, which is what we started with.

[image: output of example code]

Comment: I guess this is approximately right. But it's still a bit wrong, yeah? You've added all that spacing to the second row. But now the text is too far to the left---it is positioned as if the `\phantom` part were not `phantom` but written normally, yeah?

Comment: @SamOT -- The text of the first line is to the left because I applied `\noindent`.  It would have been more "natural" if I had added two lines of text.  (Okay; I'll consider changing that.)  The purpose was to establish the location of the edges of the text block.  The line following the display is intended as "continuation of the paragraph", thus not inented.

Comment: Sure, I wasn't thinking that it's an indent. If you take away the `\phantom` command, then you'll see that the second line is now longer than the last. Thus, it is incorrectly centred. I mean, it's really not a big deal at all! But is is till incorrect. I'll probably just go with your answer, though, as it's the closest to correct :) -- I was just surprised that there isn't a simple solution to this simple question! I can't be the first person to want to do this =P

Comment: @SamOT -- I was part of the technical support team at the American Math Society since TeX was adopted there.  The suggested "adjustment" is the approach taken in the AMS book and journal production for final cleanup.  As noted in my answer, this is much easier than trying to create a custom environment.  And it follows the philosophy in the TeXbook, which is that sometimes manual adjustments are needed or desirable.

Comment: Ah, that's cool! But yeah, my point still stands that it is incorrectly centred. You can see this by taking away your `\phantom` command---leave what inside it, though! Sorry for not making that clear. This way, you can see the spacing. I can just replace the `\phantom{...}` command with `\hspace{...}` and find the approximate spacing. If you remove the `\phantom` part, so that the text inside it is printed, you can see that it's actually qutie a long way off correct

Comment: @SamOT -- It's certainly reasonable to measure the "overage" and use that dimension in an `\hspace` command.  (And admittedly, I was guesstimating when I added the `\quad` instead of trying to match the ending bits of the first parenthesized expression.)  But in this example, it's clear how the adjusted display is positioned between the margins.  None of the other answers try to show the page width, so centering relative to the page isn't clear.

Comment: Also, to be honest, if it's off by `0.5em`, I think it's probably fine XD -- no-one's going to notice in the paper unless it's way off

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there isn't a simple solution, perhaps surprisingly. @Imran shows how to do it properly, but with the `IEEE` package, which is a bit different.

Barbara and egreg have shown some approximations. Both get the centralisation slightly wrong, but only bit a minor amount, and this could be manually adjusted.
So, since there isn't a solution, I thought I'd put in my best cheat. This does get the exact desired result---including correct centralisation---but it needs slight refinement each time. It's basically doing the horizontal alignment manually.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Without any spacing adjustment, the second $\coloneqq$ on the second row would be further to the right and on the first row. If it were the other way around, then the \verb|\mathrlap|/\verb|\phantom|/\verb|\mathllap| needs to be done on the second line.
\begin{align*}
    N_0 &\coloneqq \mathrlap{L_0,} \phantom{0, \quad S_{k+1}} \mathllap{N_k} \coloneqq L_{f(k+1)} / L_{f(k)} \\
    S_0 &\coloneqq 0, \quad S_{k+1} \coloneqq S_k + 2 d^2 L_{f(k)} T_{f(k)} N_k; \\
    C_k &\coloneqq \cap_{i \in \overline{\mathcal Q}(i_0; N_k), \: m \in [2 d^2 L_{f(k)} N_k]} \bigl( \mathcal P_{f(k),k}(i) \cap \mathcal G_{f(k),k}(i; S_k + (m-1) T_k) \bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this alignment, you have only one `&` per line, so using the `\*lap`s in the way you've done here, you could use a single `amsmath` `align` structure.  Not trying to push that alternative, just suggesting that there are quite a few different ways to look at the problem.  (I don't see an approach that avoids use of some `\*lap` *somewhere* in the coding.  Consider what you might have to do if one of the elements preceding the first relation were quite a bit longer than the others)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed. I hav eactually used `align`, if you notice! :) -- I agree, it seems that `\math*lap` is needed *somewhere*. This way has the advantage of getting the spacing *perfect*, but it is quite fiddly! In the real world, yours and egreg's solutions are probably better. Yours gets closer to correct, but his is a bit more "algorithmic": no guessing of lengths.

Comment: I feel I've learnt quite a bit from this question! It's a shame there's no simple functionality for this. Some kind of 'multi-column' option. Ah well, I've learnt some stuff so that's good! =D

Comment: Oops!  I read the text, not the code.  Other people could learn something if you gave a link to the `IEEE` approach that you mention.  (Learning new things is usually good.)

Comment: It's Imran's answer. I don't know any more than he wrote there. I've never used the `IEEE` stuff, apart from one quick submission I did once---got rejected `:Sadge:`